# How to close current tab in a browser window using js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I am showing a popup with some info with the OK button...if I click OK in that popup that current browser tab only I need to close.

```js
 var win = window.open('about:blank', '_self');
 win.close();
```

currently, I'm using this button tab not close that URL only changed to about_blank

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

**Mozilla** won't let you close a tab unless it's opened by the browser.

In **Google Chrome**:
What you need is just `window.close()`.

Explanation: In your code you're referencing `window.open('about:blank', '_self');`  in a variable which by no means will close the tab. You could either do `window.close()` or `var win = window` and then `win.close()`

Comment: i have tried this way also but I am getting warnings like this below: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them